# X-axis is inverted when changing from front to behind using RotateAround

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

I'm using a pad to control the rotation of an object around another one.
The first problem I have to solve is that when using RotateAround, when I change from front to behind, the x-axis is inverted.

I fixed it with this:

```
if (lookAtItem.position.z - camera.transform.position.z > 0)
        {

            camera.RotateAround(lookAtItem.position, Vector3.right, _ComandValues[5] * _RightStickScale);
        }
        else
        {
            camera.RotateAround(lookAtItem.position, Vector3.left, _ComandValues[5] * _RightStickScale);
        }
```

I simply use the position to understand if I'm behind or in front of the given object.

Now the second problem shows up:

When `lookAtItem.position.z - camera.transform.position.z` is around 0 and I try to rotate around the x-axis, the program changes too fast from `lookAtItem.position.z - camera.transform.position.z > 0` to `lookAtItem.position.z - camera.transform.position.z < 0`, and makes the camera go crazy (I am rotating the camera).

So does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I fixed it 2 minutes after I made the question. -_-

Note that I can use this solution only because the camera has a lookat script with the item to rotate around as target (if you don't have that you have to cry a lot with Orthonormal basis).

Solution:

Replace the code with this:

```
camera.position += camera.transform.up * _LeftStickScale * _ComandValues[5]
```